# Programatically create PowerPoint layout using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am creating an Excel macro in VBA that will take data from rows and fill in a PowerPoint using that data.  I have created a layout of text boxes in a slide that I would like to be able to apply to every new slide that is created, but I need to do this **without** having a template for it.  The issue with templates is that I would then need every user who wants to use this to have the template installed.  I have tried keeping the layout in a hidden slide and pasting it into the presentation but when I do so, they layout does not stay the same (they are all stacked on top of one another) and they do not keep their function as a text box.  What would be the proper way of going about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exact problem was eventually solved by saving the shape objects in a hidden sheet in Excel, populating them using VBA, and then using the following code to paste into a slide:

```
Sheets("template").Activate
Sheets("template").Shapes("myShape").Copy
activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteDefault).Select
```

This leaves them as shape objects and editable within PowerPoint.

Note that general good practice is to avoid Activate and Select statements.  This code was not used in the final product, and serves only as a reference.

Answer (score 2):

> The issue with templates is that I would then need every user who wants to use this to have the template installed

Not really. While it might be preferably from a performance perspective, to have the template saved locally, you should be able to use a template from a shared/network location.

Would that approach work?

If not, please show the code you are using to copy the slide.  Presumably if you have defined a custom layout in the presentation's Master Layout, copy/paste should work.  I have tested this with textboxes and with text placeholders.

Comment: I have worked around this issue by revising the requirements to no longer require editing capabilities.  The layout is now created and populated within a hidden Excel sheet, and pasted into PPT as an image.  Thank you for your reply.